# Prevent sharing of user credentials

Tags: php, mysql

Every school has a username and a password that is being used by all students in that school. The service that I am offering to schools is not free and of course I want to sell it to as many customers as possible. The problem is that any student can share the username and password of their school to somebody else, and this way, many people will access my site because they know the username and password of one of the schools. So, my question is:

How can I allow access to my website from one district(region) only? Lets say that I want people to access my site from New York City only. How can I accomplish that? I am thinking of Using IP adresses, but are they reliable? what else I can use to improve my goal? I am using PHP with MYSQL database.

Comment: Just find out the IP address for the school network and check for incoming values that match. Although there's probably a better way to go about it.

Comment: @DevinYoung that is why I asked my question.. I want to know the better way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IP addresses *in general* are not reliable for access control (many unrelated users e.g. [AOL users behind a proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AOL), Starbucks customers on free WiFi) etc can share an IP address, while a single user can have multiple IP addresses during a session (try driving a few miles down the road with a smart phone).

In *this case*, the IP may well be reliable for the intended purpose.  Depending on the country you're talking about, I would suspect that the IP addresses of a school will be fairly static (note... IP addresses.  They may well have more than one.).

Rather than restrict access by IP address, I would recommend that you *log* IP addresses that are used to access the site.  Examine the list periodically, and if you detect *appreciable* levels of misuse, issue a new password for the school in question.

Comment: Great idea, never thought of it. You deserve +1